# PHP Include from folder outside directory

Tags: php, include

Hi guys i have a question.

I have a folder structure as below

```
TMS
 |-css (folder)
   |-bootstrap.css
   |-custom.css
 |-js (folder)
   |-jquery.js
 |-header.php
 |-footer.php
 |-employee.php
 | training (folder)
   |-trainings.php
```

my question is how can i include header.php inside the trainings i tried the following but now working

```
    <?php include('http://www.example.com.ph/tms/header.php'); ?> and

   <?php include('/tms/header.php'); ?>
```

Please help me thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not include files using `http`. Just go with this one instead:

```
include '../header.php';
```

Comment: Thank you. hmm sorry but another question how can i access Jquery.js inside trainings.php? TY

Comment: define "access" - if you want to load it, just use your HTML template to do so. No need for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <?php include('../header.php'); ?>
```

in your trainings.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to go one folder back,means outside traning folder and then include your file:see below

```
<?php include('../header.php'); ?>
```